# How do I copy file contents to another file?

Tags: ruby, file-io

As basic as this seems, I simply can't manage to copy the contents of one file to another. Here is my code thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

Dir.chdir( "/mnt/Shared/minecraft-server/plugins/Permissions" )

flist = Dir.glob( "*" )

flist.each do |mod|
    mainperms = File::open( "AwesomeVille.yml" )
    if mod == "AwesomeVille.yml"
        puts "Shifting to next item..."
        shift
    else
        File::open( mod, "w" ) do |newperms|
            newperms << mainperms
        end
    end
    puts "Updated #{ mod } with the contents of #{ mainperms }."
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that this isn't the completely approved way, but

```
 IO.readlines(filename).join('') # join with an empty string because readlines includes its own newlines
```

Will load a file into a string, which you can then output into newperms just like it was a string. There's good chance the reason this isn't working currently is that you are trying to write an IO handler to a file, and the IO handler isn't getting converted into a string in the way you want it to.

However, another fix might be

```
 newperms << mainperms.read
```

Also, make sure you close mainperms before the script exits, as it might break something if you don't.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helped very much, thank you! I had not considered using the read method.

Comment: I would be very careful with this solution as it has scalability issues. `IO#readlines` slurps the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 7):

Why copy the contents of one file to another? Why not use either the OS to copy the file, or use Ruby's built-in [`FileUtils.copy_file`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-copy_file)?

```
ri FileUtils.copy_file
FileUtils.copy_file

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  copy_file(src, dest, preserve = false, dereference = true)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Copies file contents of src to dest. Both of src and
dest must be a path name.
```

A more flexible/powerful alternate is to use Ruby's built-in [`FileUtils.cp`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp):

```
ri FileUtils.cp
FileUtils.cp

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  cp(src, dest, options = {})

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Options: preserve noop verbose

Copies a file content src to dest.  If dest is a
directory, copies src to dest/src.

If src is a list of files, then dest must be a directory.

  FileUtils.cp 'eval.c', 'eval.c.org'
  FileUtils.cp %w(cgi.rb complex.rb date.rb), '/usr/lib/ruby/1.6'
  FileUtils.cp %w(cgi.rb complex.rb date.rb), '/usr/lib/ruby/1.6', :verbose => true
  FileUtils.cp 'symlink', 'dest'   # copy content, "dest" is not a symlink
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
IO.copy_stream mainperms, mod
```

[§ copy_stream](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-copy_stream)